# Webpack error for vue.js webpack template when using sass

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass, vue-cli

I'm newbie in Vue.js and webpack and I don't know if it's issue with packages or my mistake

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new vue project from webpack template

```
~ vue init webpack sass-test
? Project name sass-test
? Project description A Vue.js project
? Author dvec <dvecend@gmail.com>
? Vue build standalone
? Install vue-router? Yes
? Use ESLint to lint your code? No
? Set up unit tests No
? Setup e2e tests with Nightwatch? No
? Should we run `npm install` for you after the project has been created? (recommended) npm
~ cd sass-test
```

2. Install packages (according to [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#referencing-assets))

```
~ npm install -D sass-loader sass
```

3. Edit src/components/HelloWorld.vue (according to [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#referencing-assets))

```
Old: <style scoped>
New: <style lang="scss" scoped>
```

4. Run

```
~ npm run dev
```

5. Receive error log:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                               03:45:32

 error  in ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Module build failed: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:121:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1039:7)
    at getSassOptions (/private/tmp/sass-test/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/utils.js:160:37)
    at Object.loader (/private/tmp/sass-test/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:36:49)

 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-469af010","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue 4:14-375 13:3-17:5 14:22-383
 @ ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

What I've tried:

1. Reinstalling vue-cli
2. Changing sass to less (same steps to reproduce, different error)
3. Adding rule to **webpack.conf** ([docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass))
4. Adding style resource in **vue.config.js** ([docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#automatic-imports))
5. Adding .concat with parameters to **utils.js** ([docs](https://vue-loader-v14.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html))

I admit it may be a platform dependent error. Steps above was tested on macOS Catalina 10.15.6. Reply if you can't reproduce this error

Comment: If you're new to Vue (and Webpack), I strongly suggest you use version 4 of the CLI ~ https://cli.vuejs.org/. In fact, you appear to be using the latest guide but `vue init webpack sass-test` is definitely v2. You'll want to uninstall `vue-cli` and install `@vue/cli`

Comment: If you're following a guide that said to install `vue-cli`, find a newer guide. The official docs are probably the best starting point

Comment: @Phil ok, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Install this dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "nuxt": "^2.14.6",
    "nuxt-buefy": "^0.4.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "pug": "^3.0.0",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0"
  }
```

And you index.vue

```
<template lang="pug">
  section.hero.is-fullheight
    .hero-body
      .column.is-12-desktop.is-12-mobile
        .columns.is-multiline.is-mobile.is-centered.is-vcentered
          p.celular Hola
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Inicio',
}
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
.celular
  background: black
</style>
```